# With cytoscape.js how to automatically expand the height of the container of a graph?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is it possible to automatically expand the height of the container of a graph, according to the size of the graph?

I want to display lots of graphs of different sizes on a web page, without having to specify the height of each DOM container.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score -1):

### **Answer:**

It is not the best solution to change anything regarding the container of cytoscape.

### **Alternative for you:**

It is far better to work with the padding of the graph in order to display the graph in a dynamic/suitable way. The easiest way to do that, is to add your nodes and run your layout and then, when the layout is loaded, you can call [`cy.fit(cy.elements(), yourPadding)`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.fit).

> In cytoscape, padding is handled exactly the same way as in css, so you just calculate (based on the number of nodes maybe?) the appropriate padding for your graph and fit it to the viewport.

Additionally, you can always wrap things up with a slick ease-in animation to top things off.

### **Code:**

Snippet works when you click on `edit the above snippet` and run it in the snippet editor, here the function does not work due to the size limitation and I can't be bothered to adjust it without seeing the outcome in the editor.

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [
    {
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(id)",
        "text-valign": "bottom",
        "text-halign": "center",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px",
        "border-color": "black",
        "border-opacity": "1",
        "background-image":
          "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7272/7633179468_3e19e45a0c_b.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ":selected",
      css: {
        "background-color": "black",
        "line-color": "black",
        "target-arrow-color": "black",
        "source-arrow-color": "black"
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: "n0" } },
      { data: { id: "n1" } },
      { data: { id: "n2" } },
      { data: { id: "n3" } },
      { data: { id: "n4" } },
      { data: { id: "n5" } },
      { data: { id: "n6" } },
      { data: { id: "n7" } },
      { data: { id: "n8" } },
      { data: { id: "n9" } },
      { data: { id: "n10" } },
      { data: { id: "n11" } },
      { data: { id: "n12" } },
      { data: { id: "n13" } },
      { data: { id: "n14" } },
      { data: { id: "n15" } },
      { data: { id: "n16" } }
    ],
    edges: [
      { data: { source: "n0", target: "n1" } },
      { data: { source: "n1", target: "n2" } },
      { data: { source: "n1", target: "n3" } },
      { data: { source: "n2", target: "n7" } },
      { data: { source: "n2", target: "n11" } },
      { data: { source: "n2", target: "n16" } },
      { data: { source: "n3", target: "n4" } },
      { data: { source: "n3", target: "n16" } },
      { data: { source: "n4", target: "n5" } },
      { data: { source: "n4", target: "n6" } },
      { data: { source: "n6", target: "n8" } },
      { data: { source: "n8", target: "n9" } },
      { data: { source: "n8", target: "n10" } },
      { data: { source: "n11", target: "n12" } },
      { data: { source: "n12", target: "n13" } },
      { data: { source: "n13", target: "n14" } },
      { data: { source: "n13", target: "n15" } }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "dagre",
    padding: 5
  }
}));
cy.unbind("click");
cy.bind("click", "node", function(event) {                // just for demonstration  purposes here
  var coll = cy.$(event.target).successors();             // get all outgoing nodes
  coll = coll.add(event.target);                          // add their source
  var removed = cy.remove(cy.elements().not(coll));       // remove all other elements
  var len = cy.nodes().length;
  var pad = (len < 10 ? (len < 5 ? (len < 3 ? (len < 2 ? 150 : 100 ) : 75 ) : 50 ) : 25);                                           // custom padding function here
  cy.animate({
  fit: {
    eles: cy.elements(),
    padding: pad
  }
}, {
  duration: 500,
  easing: 'ease-in' 
});
});
```

```css
body { 
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cy"></div>
</body>
</html>
```