# Do most (all?) cytoscape layout algorithms use the size of their container to lay out the graph?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

The great cytoscape manual [indicates](https://js.cytoscape.org/#getting-started/including-cytoscape.js) that “Cytoscape.js uses the dimensions of your HTML DOM element container for layouts and rendering at initialisation”.

It is clear to me that the `random` layout does use the container size; and it is clear that the [fit-after-layout functionality](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.fit), which computes the zoom level required to fit within the available size, does (obviously) require an available size that must be chosen beforehand.

I wonder about the other cases, though. Most layout algorithms, it seems to me, produce a result whose size does not depend on the available size. I have tested the `breadthfirst` one, for example, and it seems it does not vary when the container size is increased or decreased (with [disabled zooming](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.zoomingEnabled)).

So, does that sentence refer to only some layout algorithms and to the “auto fit” functionality only?

(My question is because I would like to request a feature that would permit to size the container depending on the rendered size (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54474870/)). This however makes sense only if the rendered size is indeed, at least in some cases, independent of the available size.)

Comment: size of canvas/container should be fixed. Why do you need to change its size? For me, it seems totally unnecessary. You can always pan, zoom, and fit elements to the canvas.

Comment: The related feature request is [here](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2940).